# Psychology Today Culture Fair IQ test question - dot moving within a star

Tags: visual, progressive-matrix

I took an IQ test at Psychology Today(https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/tests/iq/culture-fair-iq-test) and encountered this question which I wasn't able to solve:
[image]

I could not find a pattern in how the dot moves within the star. Any help in this problem is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> C
>  First row: Dot moves one place clockwise every time
>  Second row: Dot moves two places clockwise every time
>  Third row: Dot moves three places clockwise every time

Answer (score 1):

The answer is...

> F(the one on the left of the <I don't know> option)

Because...

> In each row, there is one dot on the bottom of the star, one on the middle, and one on the top. The third row is missing the dot on the middle, so the answer is F(the one on the left of the <I don't know> option).

Comment: Hmm... That's a pretty good explanation! But I do think that this is wrong tho... I originally also thought that this is F, just like you!